# xmllint match and extract value

Tags: xml, xpath, xmllint

I would like to pull only "image" from the xml but I'm getting an error since the first couple ones don't include "image".

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<document>
    <job name="Job1">
        <type>
            <description>
            </description>
        </type>
    </job>
    <job name="Job2">
        <type>
            <description>
            </description>
        </type>
    </job>
    <job name="Job3">
        <type>
            <description>
                <image>
                    <png></png>
                </image>
            </description>
        </type>
    </job>
</document>
```

How can it skip the first two and match the third image tag?

```
xmllint --xpath "//*[local-name()='document']/job/type/description/image/png/text()" file
```

Comment: What error, *exactly*? Your code should already do what you describe. Also, why all that mess with `local-name`? Are there namespaces in play you aren't showing us?

Comment: @MathiasMüller, ...though in the example document given, that `png` has no child text node. The error, which the OP chose not to provide in their question, was "XPath set is empty".

Comment: An XPath query acts, in many ways, like a SQL join -- it already *does* continue to look for elements for which all the specifications line up, rather than giving up if the first path it starts down doesn't work out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I modify only one line of your input file, changing

```
<png></png>
```

to

```
<png>Some text goes here</png>
```

...then your code works perfectly as already written. Thus, the error has nothing at all to do with the first few `description`s having no `png`.

---

Mind you, since you don't have any namespaces defined, you don't need to mess with `local-name()` at all.

```
xmllint --xpath "/document/job/type/description/image/png/text()"
```

...works just as well.

Comment: ...after copy-and-pasting the exact input you gave here (as opposed to the original file you didn't show us), and changing the one line given?

Comment: plus 1, The canonical path expression would also replace `//` with `/`.

Comment: @MathiasMüller, indeed. Adjusted appropriately, and now that much more efficient.